# amazon aws s3 video how to check original resolution

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

Im using com.amazonaws in my app.
It works way that client ( desktop or mobile ) uploads video to aws, and from backend Im pusing there job request.

```
awsTranscoderClient.createJob(reqData.asAWSJobRequest)
```

but of course its a problem because I set all the time to transcode to 720p, 480p and hls. Where there is no point in 480p videos to do the job for 720 ;)

I can check video size for example:

```
awsS3VideoClient.getObjectMetadata(new GetObjectMetadataRequest(instanceBucket, reqData.input.key)).getContentLength()
```

But I can find any information how to check original video resolution :(
Is there some way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Any update? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Yep me too, it's weird that aws transcode doesn't support this crucial features => smart transcoding